# Javascript Dropdown Menu Addition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

right now on my page you can select add to basket and it will add them up in the total. I am trying to change it so you can select between 1 and 3 and it will add them together in the total but im unsure h=of how to change my page so it will do this?

Current Script:

```
<script>
    var w = 0
    var x = 19.99
    var y = 24.99

    function total1()
    {
        w = w + x
        document.getElementById('Total').value= w;
    }


    function total2()
    {
        w = w + y
        document.getElementById('Total').value= w;
    }
 </script>
```

Table to select options and display them:

```
<table id="t2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="item1.png" alt="Sunset Boulevard T-Shirt Men" style="width:350x;height:250px">
        </td>

        <td>
            <img src="item2.png" alt="Sunset Boulevard T-Shirt Woman" style="width:350x;height:250px">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <p id="price">£19.99</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p id="price">£24.99</p>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value= "Add To Basket" onclick ="total1()">
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="button" value= "Add To Basket" onclick ="total2()">             
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>

<h3 id="header3"></h3>

<div id="all">
    Basket: <input type="text" id="Total"  disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

Comment: This might help? [http://jsfiddle.net/YPYz8/](http://jsfiddle.net/YPYz8/).

Comment: @Gofoboso I think that comment was for a different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but you could simply just add a count to the number of products.

The other option you could do is add a select drop down list (DDL) in there they select the number of products they want and then just multiply the value of the DDL by the price of the item on change of the select.

```
var w = 0
var x = 19.99
var y = 24.99
var count1 = 0, count2 = 0;

function total1() {
    if(count1 < 3){
        w = w + x
        document.getElementById('Total').value= w;
        count1++;
    }
}

function total2() {
    if(count1 < 3){
        w = w + y
        document.getElementById('Total').value= w;
        count2++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `select` with the allowed number of quantities next to the "Add to basket" button. In your case you want between 1 and 3, so it's a simple one:

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

The `id` would be "select1" for the first box, and "select2" for the second box (kind of following the same name convention that you use for the functions).

Then in the `total1()` and `total2()` functions, you can easily read the value of the `select` and multiply the price by it:

```
w = w + x * document.getElementById("select1").value;
```

You can see the code on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0g2hvvL/1/) or below:

```js
var w = 0
var x = 19.99
var y = 24.99

function total1()
{
    w = w + x * document.getElementById("select1").value;
    document.getElementById('Total').value= w;
}


function total2()
{
    w = w + y * document.getElementById("select2").value;;
    document.getElementById('Total').value= w;
}
```

```html
<table id="t2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="item1.png" alt="Sunset Boulevard T-Shirt Men" style="width:350x;height:20px">
        </td>
        
        <td>
           <img src="item2.png" alt="Sunset Boulevard T-Shirt Woman" style="width:350x;height:20px">
       </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <p id="price">£19.99</p>
        </td>

        <td>
            <p id="price">£24.99</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="select1">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value= "Add To Basket" onclick ="total1()">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="select2">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value= "Add To Basket" onclick ="total2()">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>

<h3 id="header3"></h3>

<div id="all">
    Basket: <input type="text" id="Total"  disabled="disabled" >
</div>
```

Comment: As a side comment: you may want to clean your code. Right now there are some things that are a bit off and that you may want to fix too (e.g.: non-closed tags, empty `id`s, or duplicated `id`s)

Comment: Thanks @BramDriesen for updating the code. I hadn't realized that id had changed on the question too